# LEFT JOIN on PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried the same code below on my c# app and it works fine, but when i tried the same code on php with the tweak of instead of column number on c# i replaced it with column name but the result is different.

```
$sql ="SELECT 
        `adexposure`.`symbol`, 
        `adexposure`.`netvolume`, 
        `fxexposure`.`netvolume`, 
        `adexposure`.`lastupdate` 
    FROM `adexposure` 
    LEFT JOIN `fxexposure` ON `adexposure`.`symbol` = `fxexposure`.`symbol`";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows>0)
{
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Symbol</th>";
            echo "<th>Net Volume A</th>";
            echo "<th>Net Volume B</th>";
            echo "<th>Last Update</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>" .$row["symbol"]."</td>";
                            echo "<td>" .$row["netvolume"]."</td>";
                            echo "<td>" .$row["netvolume"]."</td>";
                            echo "<td>" .$row["lastupdate"]."</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";                     
            }
            echo "</table>";
 }
 else
 {
            echo "0 results";
 }
```

Result should be:

```html
<table border=1>
    <tr>
    <th>Symbol</th>
    <th>Net Volume A</th>
    <th>Net Volume B</th>
    <th>Last Update</th>
    </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>BITCOIN</td>
    <td>2.5</td>
    <td>3.5</td>
    <td>2018.02.05 10:44</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>LITECOIN</td>
    <td>1.5</td>
    <td>5.5</td>
    <td>2018.02.05 10:44</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>HASHCOIN</td>
    <td>0.5</td>
    <td>0.5</td>
    <td>2018.02.05 10:44</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

but thats not the case.
The result shows both net volume of fxexposure.netvolume.

I hope you can help me with this.

Thanks...

Comment: _LEFT JOIN on PHP..._ There is no LEFT JOIN on _php_ Please add a proper title to your question

Comment: Make an alias for one of the netvolume's. Like `fxexposure.netvolume AS fx_netvolume` and then fetch it with: `$row['fx_netvolume']`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks.

Comment: since `adexposure.symbol = fxexposure.symbol` the result would have the value shown if the  both tables have the same. if fxexposure.symbol value is not present on adexposure.symbol value, the symbol will not be shown on the query. How to show values that are not present on the other table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just a suggestion you have two time  netvolumn so you should use alias

```
sql ="SELECT 
    `adexposure`.`symbol`, 
    `adexposure`.`netvolume`, 
    `fxexposure`.`netvolume` as netvolume2, 
    `adexposure`.`lastupdate` 
FROM `adexposure` 
LEFT JOIN `fxexposure` ON `adexposure`.`symbol` = `fxexposure`.`symbol`";


while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" .$row["symbol"]."</td>";
                        echo "<td>" .$row["netvolume"]."</td>";
                        echo "<td>" .$row["netvolume2"]."</td>";
                        echo "<td>" .$row["lastupdate"]."</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";                     
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you assign an `alias` to the returned colums you can address them correctly in the php

```
$sql ="SELECT 
        `adexposure`.`symbol`, 
        `adexposure`.`netvolume` as `netvolume_A`, /* ALIAS */
        `fxexposure`.`netvolume` as `netvolume_B`, 
        `adexposure`.`lastupdate` 
    FROM `adexposure` 
    LEFT JOIN `fxexposure` ON `adexposure`.`symbol` = `fxexposure`.`symbol`";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows>0)
{
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Symbol</th>";
            echo "<th>Net Volume A</th>"; 
            echo "<th>Net Volume B</th>";
            echo "<th>Last Update</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>" .$row["symbol"]."</td>";
                            echo "<td>" .$row["netvolume_A"]."</td>";<!-- /* ALIAS */ -->
                            echo "<td>" .$row["netvolume_B"]."</td>";
                            echo "<td>" .$row["lastupdate"]."</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";                     
            }
            echo "</table>";
 }
 else
 {
            echo "0 results";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Read these two lines carefully:

```
echo "<td>" .$row["netvolume"]."</td>";
echo "<td>" .$row["netvolume"]."</td>";
```

You are using the same name to mean two different things, so there is no way for PHP to give a different result on those lines.

The solution is to give the values unique column aliases in your SQL:

```
`adexposure`.`netvolume` as netvolume_as, 
`fxexposure`.`netvolume` as netvolume_fx,
```

And then those are the names in your PHP:

```
echo "<td>" .$row["netvolume_as"]."</td>";
echo "<td>" .$row["netvolume_fx"]."</td>";
```